# Integrate the solution of a the Matrix differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I have:

$\dot{\textbf{x}}=A{\textbf{x}}$

where A is a nxn matrix.

This equation has solution:

$\textbf{x}(t)=e^{\textbf{A}t}\textbf{x}(0)$

A book i'm reading states that:

$\textbf{x}(t_{2})=e^{\textbf{A}(t_{2}-t_{1})}\textbf{x}(t_{1})$

However,i don't know if the last equation is correct since i wasn't able to deduce it by myself. Can you show me all the passages ? Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is autonomous. This means that with $x(t)$ a solution also any function $x_a(t)=x(t+a)$ is a solution with $x_a(0)=x(a)$.

In your instance, $x(t)=e^{tA}x(0)$ and $x_a(t)=e^{tA}x_a(0)=e^{tA}x(a)$. Now replace $t$ with $t-a$ to find
$$
x(t)=x((t-a)+a)=e^{(t-a)A}x(a).
$$

In general you will find that for the flow $\phi(t;x_0)$ of an autonomous system you have the (semi-)group property $\phi(t+s; x_0)=\phi(t;\phi(s;x_0))$.

Comment: Why $x_a(t)=e^{tA}x_a(0)$ ?? Shouldn't it be $x_a(t)=e^{(t+a)A}x_a(0)$ ?

Comment: No, $x_a$ itself is the solution of the IVP $x_a(0)=x(a)$. Of course you have additionally that $x_a(t)=x(t+a)=e^{(t+a)A}x(0)=e^{tA}e^{aA}x(0)=e^{tA}x(a)$ etc.

Comment: Why $e^{aA}x(0)=x(a)$ ?