# Where the idea of eigenvalue method for System of ODEs came from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading [this](https://www.unf.edu/~mzhan/chapter4.pdf) pdf.

In the chapter 2, the author says:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiXUn.png)

Suddenly the author states he has the idea that solution can be in the form
$\textbf{x}(t)=\textbf{v}e^{\lambda t}$.
However, i don't know where this idea came from. What is the intuition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ode is of order 1, the solution should involve the exponential function. Now consider an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the function $\phi(t)=\mathbf{v}e^{\lambda t}$. Now calculate $\phi'(t)$. This is simply
$$\phi'(t)=\lambda\mathbf{v}e^{\lambda t}$$
If $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, we can write $$\phi'(t)=\lambda\mathbf{v}e^{\lambda t}=A\mathbf{v}e^{\lambda t}=A\phi(t)$$
Hence $\phi$ is a solution of $x'(t)=Ax(t)$, when $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me here ?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106358/integrate-the-solution-of-a-the-matrix-differential-equation

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Euler method to $x'=Ax$ leads, similar to the scalar case, to
$$
x(t)\approx(I+\frac{t}NA)^Nx(0).
$$
Again following the scalar case one can perform the limit $N\to\infty$ to find the exponential series
$$
x(t)=I+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}A^kx(0)
$$
At this point one might be tempted to apply the eigen-decomposition of $A$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me here ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106358/integrate-the-solution-of-a-the-matrix-differential-equation

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the intuition comes from the one dimensional version. When your equation has the form
\begin{equation}
x'(t) = cx(t)
\end{equation}
where $c \in \mathbb{R}$, what you are trying to do is finding a function whose derivative is “almost the same” as the original function, modulo a real coefficient. This leads to considering the exponential function (and sometimes the exponential function is exactly defined as the unique solution to a certain Cauchy problem where the ODE is of this form).

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me here ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106358/integrate-the-solution-of-a-the-matrix-differential-equation